# Best XT pads for weak hand strength

Tags: brakes, pads

After a serious crash that left my right hand with plates and pins installed, can anyone suggest a grippy pad for my rear XT disk brake? My hand strength is about 30% of normal.
Thank you.
David

Comment: There aren't any - but since its your back brake its less important.  Can you do hand exercises to help build it up more ?   
I'd be worried about even holding the bars firmly during a normal ride :\

Comment: The only way I can think of to compensate for that would be to move the lever to the other side if you've lost enough hand/finger power to brake normally.

Comment: If your current brakes are mechanical, I'd suggest switching to hydraulic, and with larger disks.

Comment: Note that with many levers you can adjust the lever to sit closer to the bar, as would be needed to accommodate smaller hands.  For you this might position the lever such that you can better use your available strength on it.

Comment: Disks of V brakes? I can lock my good condition XT Discs with one finger, so I wonder if it is more about articulation than strength.  Organic pads and bigger rotors would make a difference.

Comment: It may be worth exploring back-pedal brakes (aka coaster brakes)  These require reverse tension on the chain so will not work with a normal derailleur bike.  If you want gears still, then an Internally Geared Hub + coaster brake may work best of all for you.

Comment: By having XT brakes I suspect it's a mountain bike or I would suggest other brake options like a coaster or (bad for the knees in my opinion) fixie hub.

Answer (score 1):

I can't offer brand and product suggestions but I will say that you could opt for organic pads over sintered for better initial bite. That may compensate for the reduced strength. There's a decent writeup on [Pinkbike](http://www.pinkbike.com/news/brake-pad-information-2009.html) which coveres the differences between the 2 types of pad.

If you're going to be riding in wet and muddy conditions though, it may be best to swap out for some sintered pads for that ride. Can you get someone you trust to help bed your brakes in? On new and freshly cleaned rotors it makes a huge difference to how much braking force is needed.

Can you brake using a single finger? That should allow you to keep most fingers on the grip for better confidence. My levers are adjusted so the hook at the end of the lever is in line with my index finger.

Although it's a rear brake you can increase your rotor size, possibly by 2 steps if you're running standard 160mm discs. That should give you an increased mechanical advantage. I recently increased my front rotor to 180mm using a postmount adapter. It's a simple job.

The other extreme would be to use one lever to operate both brakes. I've seen a junction box for brakes hoses recently that will allow such a thing. The downside is that you'd probably also need a lever with a larger volume. I think Hope do something that should do the trick.

Lastly, I'm sure you're doing you physio but keep at it. I smashed my scaphoid and several years on I'm stil paying the price. Keep flexing, stretching and doing your grip exercises. If you don't everything tightens back up again and you have to start over.

Nice to see you're still eager to ride though. Good luck.

Comment: Many jurisdictions in the world require bicycles to have two independent braking systems.  That's a front and a rear, or a front and a single-speed.  Joining both brakes to one lever could be seen as one system - what if the lever fails...? No Brake!